# cannot find -lgsl and -lgslcblas

Tags: python, c, mingw, gsl

I am trying to compile a software called MRtrix in windows. It uses a python build script, (I have uploaded it here: http://pastebin.com/XnufSz53)

when I run this script I get the error pasted bellow.

I guess that the GSL libraries are not being found and I need to add a -L pointing to the library but because the compilation is being done by the python script I do not really now how to do this. Currently GnuWin is installed at C:\GnuWin32\

Thank you in advance,

Jesse

============================================================

```
ERROR: [LD] lib\mrtrix-0_2_11.dll

g++ -shared lib\image\format\base.o lib\math\vector.o lib\file\mmap.o lib\args.o
 lib\image\format\dicom.o lib\file\dicom\select_cmdline.o lib\file\key_value.o l
ib\image\axis.o lib\image\format\mrtrix.o lib\image\interp.o lib\data_type.o lib
\point.o lib\image\mapper.o lib\file\dicom\element.o lib\file\dicom\mapper.o lib
\file\dicom\patient.o lib\file\dicom\quick_scan.o lib\image\object.o lib\mrtrix.
o lib\image\format\xds.o lib\file\dicom\dict.o lib\app.o lib\math\matrix.o lib\f
ile\config.o lib\image\format\mri.o lib\file\dicom\image.o lib\math\linalg.o lib
\file\dicom\study.o lib\file\dicom\series.o lib\image\name_parser.o lib\image\fo
rmat\list.o lib\file\dicom\tree.o lib\image\fft.o lib\image\header.o lib\image\f
ormat\analyse.o lib\image\format\nifti1.o -LC:/gtkmm64/lib -lglibmm-2.4 -lgobjec
t-2.0 -lsigc-2.0 -lgthread-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lintl -lgsl -lgslcblas -lz -o lib\mrt
rix-0_2_11.dll

failed with output:

c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot fin
d -lgsl
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot fin
d -lgslcblas
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

============================================================

Comment: Looking through this script, it seems like there is no way to do that. It's very inflexible and offers too little parameters to tweak. The only way you could move further is to put both `gsl` and `gslcblas` into either MinGW distribution library paths, or to `C:\gtkmm64\lib` (which is somehow present in your previous invocation). That's a bitter hack, but it's the developers of MRtrix to blame for such a crap.

Comment: @Haroogan thanks for the reply, I copied libgsl.a and libgslcblas.a to C:\gtkmm64\lib but now I get the following error: http://pastebin.com/uTW6A7wZ

Comment: Well, yeah, something is wrong with your GLib, it might be outdated, or improperly linked. All in all the scheme of building all that stuff through this python script seems very frustrating because your are not in control of anything, neither linkage nor dependecies. I think your best bet would be to receive some help from MRtrix developers directly since no one knows the code and dependencies better than they do.